# How to zip ( combine iterators ) that don't handle boost::prior

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, range

I have the following code to generate tuples of adjacent pairs in a range. This works for bidirectional ranges but not for forward only ranged.

```
    template <typename Range>

    // Returns a range of adjacent pairs of the input range
    auto make_adjacent_range(Range const & r) -> decltype(boost::combine(
            boost::make_iterator_range(boost::begin(r), boost::prior(boost::end(r))), 
            boost::make_iterator_range(boost::next(boost::begin(r)), boost::end(r))))
    {
        return boost::combine(
            boost::make_iterator_range(boost::begin(r), boost::prior(boost::end(r))), 
            boost::make_iterator_range(boost::next(boost::begin(r)), boost::end(r)));
    }
```

**boost::prior** is not accepted with a forward only range. Is there an equally elegant solution that will work with forward ranges?

[boost::combine](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not really elegant, but you can just write a `adjacent_iterator` type. 
It's relatively tricky to get it to work for `InputIterator`, as you have to dereference before each increment

```
template <typename InputIterator>
class adjacent_iterator
{
public:
    using element_type = std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type;
    using value_type = std::pair<element_type, element_type>;
    using category = std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::category;
    // all the other typedefs

    adjacent_iterator& operator++() 
    { 
        element.first = element.second;
        if (needs_deref) element.second = *it;
        ++it;
        needs_deref = true;
        return *this;
    }

    reference operator*()
    {
        element.second = *it;
        needs_deref = false;
        return element;
    }

    // all the other members    

    friend bool operator==(adjacent_iterator lhs, adjacent_iterator rhs)
    {
        // only check the iterator
        return lhs.it == rhs.it;
    }
private:
    adjacent_iterator(element_type first, InputIterator second) 
      : element(first, {}), it(second), needs_deref(true) {}
    adjacent_iterator(InputIterator end)
      : it(end) {}

    InputIterator it;
    value_type element;
    bool needs_deref;

    // not sure how to declare this friendship
    template <typename Range>
    friend auto make_adjacent_range(Range const & r) 
    {
        auto begin = boost::begin(r);
        auto end = boost::end(r);

        using IT = decltype(boost::begin(r));
        auto elem = *begin++;
        auto b = adjacent_iterator<IT>(elem, begin);
        auto e = adjacent_iterator<IT>(end);

        return boost::make_iterator_range(b, e);
    }
};
```

Comment: I curious how much work it would be to get this up to production quality. But, yes, that's the thing I'd suggest to use for forward-only ranges

Comment: Yeah. I initially thought it would be easy to do an `InputIterator` version, but then I realised you have to dereference things very carefully

Comment: So nice :) You can use *auto* for the return types of make_adjacent_range. I'm on VS2010 so I can't use nice things like that :(

Answer (score 1):

This works, but could be quite inefficient depending on the iterator types:

```
template <typename Range>
auto make_adjacent_range(Range const & r) {
    auto n  = boost::size(r);
    auto b  = boost::begin(r);
    auto r1 = boost::make_iterator_range(b, boost::next(b, n-1));
    auto r2 = r1;
    r2.advance_begin(1);
    r2.advance_end(1);
    return boost::combine(r1, r2);
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d18a64a7e6098173)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

template <typename Range>
auto make_adjacent_range(Range const & r) {
    auto n  = boost::size(r);
    auto b  = boost::begin(r);
    auto r1 = boost::make_iterator_range(b, boost::next(b, n-1));
    auto r2 = r1;
    r2.advance_begin(1);
    r2.advance_end(1);
    return boost::combine(r1, r2);
}

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> v{1,2,3,4};

    for (auto p : make_adjacent_range(v))
        std::cout << p.get<0>() << " " << p.get<1>() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Perhaps it would be nicer to make an iterator adaptor.

Comment: Are there any ranges such that `boost::size` is O(1) which are not bidirectional?

Comment: @Caleth of course there are. However, that is not the norm. (Example: [intrusive singly-linked list with constant-time size](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/intrusive/slist.html))

Comment: If you have a function_input_iterator with infinite upper bound then I don't think this will work.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Indeed, it won't. But that wasn't in your question. Why are you trying to write super-generic facilities here? Can't you specialize the "hard" cases like the all popular (standard) library implementations do?

Comment: (FWIW, `prior(end(r))` will not do something useful for unbound ranges anyways. That's math/logic, not a coding issue).